# How configure SVN in Cpanel/WHM?

Tags: linux, apache, svn, git-svn, cpanel

I want to install SVN server in my Linax VPS with cpanel/WHM running. When checking RPM packages through WHM and SSH I saw that SVN is Installed as RPM package. How can I make it work ? I'm not that experienced with server administration. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for some time, and then eventually contacted CPanel directly. This is what I did to get it to work after some guidance from them. PS. Please ensure that SVN is already installed by calling **yum install subversion**

1. ) Log in to WHM ( I have root access )
2. ) Go to Home -> Service Configuration -> Apache Configuration
3. ) Click on Include Editor
4. ) Jump To : Pre Main Include 5) Under "I wish to edit the Pre Main configuration include file for:", select **All Versions**
5. ) Depending on your server's individual settings and paths on your server,
   add the below (I use CentOS gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat
   4.4.6-4) (GCC))

   - LoadModule dav_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_dav.so
   - LoadModule dav_svn_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
   - LoadModule authz_svn_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_svn.so

   <Location /svn>
       DAV svn
       SVNPath /data/svn/repos
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "Subversion repos"
       AuthUserFile /data/svn/svn-auth-conf
       Require valid-user
   </Location>
6. ) Click on Update
7. ) Restart Apache

If Apache restarts, you should be OK. You should then be able to (based on above configuration) to access your SVN through yourdomain.com/svn. Use the **htpasswd** command to create your **svn-auth-conf** file

One thing I am struggling with is the following error
[**Could not open the requested SVN filesystem**] but I have a strong feeling that it has to do with folder permissions relating to apache (httpd) under /data/svn/repos. I am investigating :)

These links also helped me

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache/EasyApacheCustomDirectivesOutsideVirtualHost

Comment: OK, I resolved the [Could not open the requested SVN filesystem] problem. I am using multiple SVN repositories in a single path, and should thus have changed the SVNPath /data/svn/repos directive to SVNParentPath /data/svn/repos. Restarted Apache and it works! As per http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch06s04.html and http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/threads/31004-Subversion-Sever